# Repaint an 8x8 chessboard to reach only one black square.

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, puzzle

The question I saw is as follow:
Assume an 8x8 chessboard. You can repaint all squares of a row or a colum or a 2x2 square. The goal is to attain one black square. Can you reach the goal?

Comment: what does repaint mean? how is the board initially colored?

Comment: Also see here: https://www.quora.com/Assume-an-8-times-8-chessboard-with-usual-colouring-You-may-repaint-all-the-squares-of-a-row-or-column-The-goal-is-to-attain-one-black-square-Can-you-reach-the-goal

Comment: The board is colored as a chessboard. Repaint means switching the colors of the squares. For example, if the color of a square is initially black, it will become white after repaint. If the square was initially white, it will become black after repaint.

Comment: Note you have two conflicting answers.  One is correct and one is almost correct given their differing interpretations of repainting.  You should make clear in the question (as you did in the comment) which you mean.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that repaint means inverrting the color of each square it is impossible.

Notice that initially there are $32$ black squares, notice that every move preserves the parity of the number of black squares.

Comment: It is not really true that the parity is preserved. For example, repaint the first column. Then for all rows, there are more square of one color then the other. so interchanging a row, the parity will no longer be preserved.

Comment: parity means that the number of black squares is always even.

Comment: Ah that makes sense! thx a lot!

Comment: no prob, happy to help

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

You can do it in 8 steps.

1. repaint every second column (4 steps)
2. repaint white rows (4 steps)

Comment: I don't see how this results in only one black square

Comment: The basic idea is good but you need to stop after seven steps to leave a black square and in step 2 you want to repaint three of the rows that are still mixed.  This assumes repainting turns all black squares white but does not change the white ones.  OP has clarified in a comment that this was not intended, but the original question was not clear.

Comment: @bburGsamohT , the board will be all black, whilst there's one black square.